# Certain audio files not loading on Android 'File not found'

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

I have an app that allows you to pick an audio file and then load / playback etc.

For some reason certain files do not load, even though they are selectable, and are not unusual file types, for example, I am currently trying an MP3 audio file (6.5mb).

This is the process once selected;

```
// load audio to SoundController
public void initSound(String audioPath) {
    File audioFile = new File(audioPath);
    if (audioFile.exists()) {
        String s = audioFile.getName();
        mFileName = s.substring(0, s.length() - 4);
        showProcessDialog();
        try {
            mSoundController.loadAudio(audioFile.getAbsolutePath());
            mSoundController.loadVisualizer(visualizerView, false);
            mSoundController.loadVisualizer(visualizerReverseView, true);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Cannot load audio file", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            closeProcessDiaglog();
        }
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "File not found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

The showProcessDialog;

```
void showProcessDialog() {
        isLoadedAudio = false;
        prcDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        prcDialog.setMessage("Please Wait - Loading Audio - if this dialogue appears for more than 15 seconds, your file is not compatible so please try loading a different audio file.");
        prcDialog.setCancelable(true);
        prcDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "Cancel & Try A Different Audio File",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                } );

        prcDialog.show();


    }

    // Close Process dialog
    void closeProcessDiaglog() {
        if (prcDialog.isShowing()) {
            prcDialog.dismiss();
        }
        checkAudioLoaded();
    }

    public void checkAudioLoaded() {
        sbSongProcess.setEnabled(mSoundController.isPlaying());
        if (mSoundController.isLoadedAudio()) {
            playAudio.setEnabled(true);
            playAudio.setChecked(mSoundController.isPlaying());
        } else {
            playAudio.setEnabled(false);
            playAudio.setChecked(false);
        }
    }
```

Of course also onActivityResult;

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == AppicationContants.OPEN_FILE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            mPath = data.getStringExtra("Path");
            isLoadingFile = true;

        }
    }
```

This particular mp3 file, the dialogue shows, however does not ever dismiss and the file does not load, but other files will fire the 'File not found' Toast message found in my `initSound` method.

I am struggling to understand why, these are audio files that are downloaded onto my device.

The ManagerAudioActivity.java file handles the choosing of the file / opening.

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == AppicationContants.AUDIO_PICK_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            try {
                Uri uri = data.getData();
                String arr1 = uri.toString().substring(0, uri.toString().lastIndexOf("/"));
                String id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                String path = FilePath.getPath(this, uri);
                File t = null;
                // Alternatively, use FileUtils.getFile(Context, Uri)
                if (path != null && FileUtils.isLocal(path)) {
                    t = new File(path);
                }
                mPath = path;
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), mPath, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                if(checkIfAudio(mPath)) {
                    if(t.exists()) {
                        String description = "Tempo:100 Pitch:+0 Key:+0";
                        Song newSong = new Song(t.getName().substring(0, t.getName().length() -4), description, t.getAbsolutePath());
                        if(!checkIfExisted(newSong.getName())) {
                            currentCategory.getSongs().add(newSong);
                        }
                        
                        SongAdapter songAdapter = new SongAdapter(ManagerAudioActivity.this, currentCategory.getSongs());
                        lvListSong.setAdapter(songAdapter);
                        ((CustomAdapter) lvListCategory.getAdapter()).updateItemList(categories);
                        saveData();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "File not found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "File in wrong format", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "File not found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            
        }
    }
    
    public boolean checkIfAudio(String path)
    {
        boolean result = false;
        try {
            SoundStreamAudioPlayer audioPlayer = new SoundStreamAudioPlayer(10, path, 1.0f, 0.0f);
            result = true;
            audioPlayer = null;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "error="+e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        
        return result;
    }
    public boolean checkIfExisted(String name)
    {
        if(currentCategory!= null && currentCategory.getSongs().size()>0)
        {
            for(int i =0 ; i< currentCategory.getSongs().size() ; i++)
            {
                if(currentCategory.getSongs().get(i).getName().equals(name))
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: "I have an app that allows you to pick an audio file" -- I recommend that you update your [mcve] to show the code for the "pick" operation and how that eventually gets to your `initSound()` call.

Comment: Updated just now

Comment: I do not know what `Intent` you are using for the `startActivityForResult()` call for the `AppicationContants.AUDIO_PICK_REQUEST_CODE` request code. But, there are virtually no scenario in which you can get a "file path" from a `Uri`, because a `Uri` is not a file. Use the `Uri` itself with whatever `mSoundController` is.

Comment: `private SoundController mSoundController` is the only reference to mSoundController.

Comment: There are three calls made on `mSoundController` in `initAudio()`. In particular, you have a call to `mSoundController.loadAudio(audioFile.getAbsolutePath())`.